# Why is setting empty text node in XML not an error?

Tags: java, xml, dom

Example input:

```
 <p>    </p>
```

Example code:

```
 // assume node is the 'p' Element, then chNode is a text node
 chNode = node.getFirstChild(); 

 // set text to empty string
 chNode.setNodeValue("");
```

I would have thought setting empty text is an error, or, it would delete the text node.

Since, we have a `p` element with an empty text node.  However, if we had deleted the text node instead, would it not be the same thing?

I'm trying to understand the purpose of the empty text node.

Comment: *why* do you expect it to be an error?

Comment: @luk2302 updated question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM tends to be very relaxed about enforcing constraints; in fact, it doesn't even make much effort to specify constraints. The XDM model used by XSLT/XPath/XQuery is much stricter: it allows a free-standing zero-length text node, but as soon as you try and add such a node to a tree, it disappears. At least with this situation it's not really a problem because the DOM can be serialized to well-formed lexical XML in an obvious way. There are other cases where you can create structures in DOM that can't be serialized to well-formed XML (for example, invalid XML characters in nodes, or attributes having a namespace URI but no prefix).

Answer (score 1):

> I would have thought setting empty text is an error, or, it would delete the text node.

There is no error, since it is still a valid document.

> However, if we had deleted the text node instead, would it not be the same thing?

No. In a structural manner, an empty element is different from a deleted element.

> I'm trying to understand the purpose of the empty text node.

An empty element doesn't have *meaning* by itself. Who gives meaning is the person or application that makes use of the XML document.

These three documents are **syntactically** different from one another:

```xml
<root></root>
```

```xml
<root><p></p></root>
```

```xml
<root><p>    </p></root>
```

For a given purpose they may *mean* the same, but as for the XML specification, which defines the syntax of XML, they are different.

Comment: My question was about text nodes, not elements.  For example, a `p` element with an empty text node or no text node both get serialized as `<p />`

Comment: @dave as far as i know, element and text node mean the same. And as for your example, they got serialized by whom?

Comment: It is all about XML processing. as @nandsito said - document is valid from XML format prospective. Empty text value is a valid value for `xsd:string` type. But if there is a Schema (XSD) and XML processor properly validates document against it, there will be an error if (and only if)  element type has defined restriction to do not have empty string. Otherwise second example `<p></p>` will have empty (null) string, and third `<p>    </p>` will have a string with spaces in it. (of course if element  type is `xsd:string` and not `xsd:token`)